GPT Action + ngrok - can't get it to work
I'm trying to setup a GPT action (using custom GPT and not the API) with local server, and use ngrok as the mediator
But the GPT action request does not reach my server
Here's my setup :

I called the command line 'ngrok http 8080', which gave me https://someid.ngrok-free.app

I create an action in custom GPT with the following schema and no authentication


`{
    "openapi": "3.0.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "Test Connectivity API",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "description": "API to test connectivity by calling a specified URL and expecting a 200   status"
    },
    "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://someid.ngrok-free.app/",
      "description": "Ngrok server for testing connectivity"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Test Connectivity",
        "operationId": "testConnectivity",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful response with status 200 and 'hello' message",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "message": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "example": "Hello, HTTP!"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad request response"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`


From my local server, I started some process with C# HttpListener on port *:8080

When I try to connect with a browser to https://someid.ngrok-free.app/, everything is working and I can see it reaches my server, and I get the response in my browser
When I try to use it from the GPT action it does not reach my server at all

I never got headers to work so used TunnelMole instead. Does the same but without the warning: https://github.com/robbie-cahill/tunnelmole-client

Thanks!, tried with tmole and localtunnel - same result - via browser (or any other http request) - all ok, via gpt action - no go
